# How to render inline javascript only desktop device (width > 1024px)

Tags: javascript

How to render inline javascript only desktop device (width > 1024px)

I have to search for many codes but it doesn't work

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by render inline javascript, but I'm assuming you mean you want to run code only on devices wider than 1024px.

Perhaps something like the following would work:

```js
if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
  // Code to run on wide displays only
  console.log("This will only happen if the window is wide enough");
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth

Answer (score 1):

If you have much code, you could extract it to another file ("extra-file.js") and load it only on "big" screens.

```js
if (window.innerWidth >= 1024) {
  var jsForBigScreens = document.createElement("script");

  jsForBigScreens.type = "text/javascript";
  jsForBigScreens.src = "path/to/your/extra-file.js";

  document.body.appendChild(jsForBigScreens);
  
}
```